# How to customize about in RCP 4 application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

We are working on RCP4 envelopment and we are trying to implement about action inside menu bar. In RCP 3 application IworkbenchAction used to create this type of action but we don't have similar feature in RCP4 . Could you please some one help on this. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for commenting . In Eclipse RCP 3 to create about action we have used below code.
IWorkbenchAction m_aboutAction = ActionFactory.ABOUT.create(window);   but in RCP 4 we can'r use the IWorkbenchAction . So we re trying to implement the same feature in RCP 4 as well.

Comment: As I say in my answer there is no default About dialog or action in e4 - you have to code all this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default About dialog in a pure e4 application you have to write your own. One reason for this is that the Eclipse RCP 3 About dialog depends heavily on the 'p2' update system - many e4 RCPs don't need to include the p2 plugins.

So you just use a normal HandledMenuItem to connect to a command. By convention the command should have the id `org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction` - this will allow Eclipse to move the menu to the correct place on macOS.